# Sitecore 9.1 initial Password in Azure

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I believe by default the SiteCore initial password for 8 is admin/b. What is the default password for SiteCore 9.1?

I have installed it in Azure and not able to reset the password, its giving an error saying `Mail server settings has not been configured. Password recovery is not possible.`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't looked,

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15260/is-sitecore-9-1-admin-password-no-longer-b
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/what-is-the-default-password-in-sitecore-9?rq=1

By the way, you need to check the Sitecore community forums for any queries/references.
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-connect-with-the-sitecore-community